# C++ default output stream what causes an error?

Tags: c++

I have opened a file to write to, and according to some conditions sometimes I want to print output to the screen and sometimes to the file. So I edited my function to be like this:

```
Cacl(const std::string &str, const ofstream &to=std::cout)
```

But I'm getting an error, what may cause this?

```
no viable conversion from 'std::__1::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') to 'const std::__1::ofstream' (aka 'const basic_ofstream<char>')
void Calculator::solve(const std::string &command, const ofstream &to=std::cout) {
```

Answer (score 6):

`std::cout` is an object of type `std::ostream` which is a base class of `std::ofstream` (it's more general than `std::ofstream`), so you could just do:

```
void Calculator::solve(const std::string &str, std::ostream &to = std::cout) {
                             // instead of ofstream ^^^^^^^
```

and now you can pass an `ofstream` object to this function as well.

Also, the `ostream` shouldn't be `const` otherwise you won't be able to write to it.

Comment: But now I can't print to it like this:             to <<element.first << endl;

Comment: invalid operands to binary expression ('const std::ostream' (aka 'const basic_ostream<char>') and 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>')
            to << element.first << endl;

Comment: The argument can't be `const`. Edited the answer.